# Enable MAC address filtering in Squid

Tags: linux, squid

Hi Please let me know how to filter internet access with MAC address on Squid....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  `/etc/squid/squid.conf` add some acls:

```
acl mac_addr1 arp ff:ff:ee:aa:00:00
acl mac_addr2 arp 00:11:22:33:44:55
http_access allow mac_addr1
http_access allow mac_addr2
http_access deny all
```

This examples allows http_access only to `mac_addr1` and `mac_addr2`.

You must have compiled `squid` with `mac` support. In order to do this add `–enable-arp-acl` to configure command.

See [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-squid-mac-address-filtering/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more rules about MAC based filtering here.

http://tecadmin.net/configure-squid-proxy-server-mac-address-based-filtering/